# How to add comma between array items PHP - Drupal

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a comma between these array items, however if I were to use implode it was just returning Array, Array.

```
function boron_taxonomy_links($node, $vid, $type, $cat) {
  if (count($node->taxonomy)){
    $tags = array();
    foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
       if ($term->vid == $vid){
          $tags[] = array('title' => $term->name . ',', 'href' => $type . '/' . $cat . '/' . $term->tid, 'attributes' => array('rel' => 'tag'));
       }
}
    if ($tags){
      return theme_links($tags, array('class'=>'links inline'));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: not enough info here. your have multiple arrays in the code and we don't know what the theme links function does. what and where are you trying to make a csv string?

Answer (score 0):

When you call implode on `$tags`, it will put a comma inbetween the string representations of the objects in the array. In your case, those objects are arrays which PHP doesn't know how to turn into a string, so it uses the string `'Array'`.

You'll want to make sure that `$tags` is populated with a string formatted the way you want. Since you don't mention how you want it to appear, I'll below is just an example.

```
function TermToString($type, $cat, $term) {
    $title = $term->name . ',';
    $href = $type . '/' . $cat . '/' . $term->tid;
    $attribures = array('rel' => 'tag');

    // combine into some string and return
    return "<a href=\"$href\" title=\"$title\" ref=\"{$attribures['rel']}\">$title</a>";
}

function boron_taxonomy_links($node, $vid, $type, $cat) {
    if (count($node->taxonomy)) {
        $tags = array();
        foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
            if ($term->vid == $vid) {
                $tags[] = TermToString($type, $cat, $term);
            }
        }
        if ($tags) {
            return theme_links($tags, array('class' => 'links inline'));
        }
    }
}
```